# Add custom parameter to PayPal

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to send custom parameter to PayPal,and receive in back with IPNPaypal.

I have added input

```
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="MyData">

    <div id="paypal-button">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="MyData">
    </div>
```

Or i need to add this parameter in paypal.Button.render?

```
 paypal.Button.render({
                                        env: 'sandbox', // or 'production'
                                        commit: true, // This will add the transaction amount to the PayPal button
                                        payment: function () {
                                            return paypalCheckoutInstance.createPayment({
                                                flow: 'checkout',   // Required
                                                amount: newPrice,   // Required
                                                currency: currency, // Required
                                              // custom: 'Thisfromrender',   not working as well                                             
                                                locale: 'en_US',    // PayPal popup language
                                                landingPageType: 'billing', //billing is for guest, login is for PayPal
                                                enableShippingAddress: true,
                                                shippingAddressEditable: false
                                            });
                                        },

                                        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {....
```

What i am missing?

Comment: I am not sure that i understand you,in the docs that you have sent have no info about custom parameters.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server